# How can I get a string from HTML to PHP?

Tags: php, html, post

Here's my HTML code:

```
<li>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <span>Get_Right| $180.000<span>
  </a>
</li>
```

And here's what I need:

When I click the "Get_Right" I want to assign a PHP variable to the name, something like $name = "Get_Right", I have tons of these li's about 50, how can I do it for one so I can replicate it for the other ones aswell?

Comment: To do that, you have to make a HTTP call. For example, have `href` leading somewhere on your server where a part of the call path is a path-parameter. Then by inspecting the URI which came in on PHP side you can extract the parameter. Or just have it be a GET method with a parameter, since you should have full control over the URI which would be queried.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. And read [mcve]. You will get more answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['button1'])){
    echo "$180.000";
}



?>



<!-- 
<li>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <span>Get_Right| $180.000<span>
    <input type="text" name="button1" value="Get Right">
  </a>
</li> -->



<form action="resolve.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Get Right">
</form>
```

I hope that helped you or at least give you a ideea to make.

Comment: That kinda destroys the li I have and all the css behind it, is there any way to make that work with a list?